# Create relationship between 2 entities in different ViewControllers

Tags: ios, objective-c

i have 2 entities Called Playlists and Songs. First i'm passing the selected playlist into my singleton by using this code:

```
optionsSingle = [rowNumber singleObj];

optionsSingle.selectedRowNow = [devices objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

the `optionsSingle.selectedRowNow` will return something like this, depending on name:

```
0xb922600 <x-coredata://053340C7-00A3-47EA-A213-4A9B6164504F/Playlists/p6> ; data: {
    playlistName = playlist1;
    songs = "<relationship fault: 0xb961480 'songs'>";
})
```

The problem is when i try to use this playlist object in the `addSongsViewController` it do not seem to work.

Im trying to include something like this to the `songsDone` method, but it wont let me use the `addSongsObject`. I've included the 2 entities to the .m file. The `optionsSingle.selectedRowNumber` is declared as as ´playlist´object type. How come i cant use this method on my playlist object that has been passed?

```
[optionsSingle.selectedRowNumber addSongsObject:newManagedObject2]
```

songsDone Method.

```
-(IBAction)songsDone:(id)sender{

    AppDelegate *appDelegate =
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    NSManagedObjectContext *context =
    [appDelegate managedObjectContext];

   Songs *newManagedObject2 = (Songs*)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Songs" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    NSDate *today= [NSDate date];


    [newManagedObject2 setValue:video.author forKey:@"author"];
    [newManagedObject2 setValue:video.videoid forKey:@"link"];
    [newManagedObject2 setValue:video.title forKey:@"songName"];
    [newManagedObject2 setValue:today forKey:@"created"];


    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![_managedObjectContext save:&error]) {

        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();

}
```

Comment: If `selectedRowNumber` contains a `Playlists` object then you should declare it as such, and not as `NSObject`. - Otherwise the compiler cannot "know" that is responds to `addSongsObject:`.

Comment: How do i declare this?

Comment: Replace `NSObject` by `Playlists` in the definition of the `selectedRowNumber` property.

Comment: This was the problem, if you could make a answer with the solution, other people might find it useful and i'll be able to approve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(From my above comment:)* If `selectedRowNumber` contains a `Playlists` object then you should declare it as such, and not as `NSObject`. Otherwise the compiler cannot "know" that it responds to `addSongsObject:`. - I.e. you should replace `NSObject` by `Playlists` in the definition of the `selectedRowNumber` property.